# Can we write a select query in an aggregate function parameter?

Tags: mysql

Can we write a select query in an aggregate function parameter?

For example, is it possible to write a SQL query like the following?

```
SELECT SUM (SELECT EMP.SAL FROM EMPLOYEE EMP) FROM EMPLOYEE E;
```

Comment: SELECT SUM (E.SAL) FROM EMPLOYEE E is probably what you need

Comment: I think what he means is that "SELECT EMP.SAL FROM EMPLOYEE EMP" is not text as shown, but a parameter (from a storproc?)

Answer (score 3):

Directly use:

```
SELECT SUM (EMP.SAL) FROM EMPLOYEE EMP
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's not necesary. The query on your question could be replaced by this:

```
SELECT SUM(EMP.SAL) FROM EMPLOYEE EMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

**No**, this is incorrect syntax.

From [SUM([DISTINCT] expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)

> Returns the sum of expr

Not a result set.

Why do you wish to do this. Show us what you are trying to achieve, and maybe we can help you better.

Comment: Is their any possible way to write Select query in Aggregate function parameter

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? What are your intensions? Show us what you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: I have a same problem actually i want to use GROUP By inside aggregate function follow the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38699752/multidimensional-array-and-aggregate-functions-in-mysql-using-php

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as `Employee.Sal` is a numeric field. (Though if these are the actual fields you are using, there is no reason not to use `Select Sum(Sal) from Employee`).

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
   Select sum(EMP.SAL) FROM EMPLOYEE EMP
```