# Multidimensional array and aggregate functions in MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mysqli, aggregate

**UPDATED**

*How to display 1 more column next to that u2 called CUMULATIVE TOTAL

it should display total number of students total payable total paid and total due based on counsellors.*

Consider i have c1,c2,c3,c4 as counsellors and u1,u2 as universities
say c1 has 5 student in each university in that case CUMULATIVE TOTAL column should show total number of students column as [c1][No of students]=10, [c1][Payable]=some value, [c1][Paid]=some value, [c1][Balence]=some value

[image]

Please check the following code and let me know is there any way to write select query inside that SUM aggregate function or any alternate solution because i want wll_invoice.total_payable should group by customer_id.

```
        <?php
define('DB_MAIN', 'localhost|user|passowd|database');

class my_db{

    private static $databases;
    private $connection;

    public function __construct($connDetails){
        if(!is_object(self::$databases[$connDetails])){
            list($host, $user, $pass, $dbname) = explode('|', $connDetails);
            $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";
            self::$databases[$connDetails] = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
        }
        $this->connection = self::$databases[$connDetails];
    }

    public function fetchAll($sql){
        $args = func_get_args();
        array_shift($args);
        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute($args);
         return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
}

$db = new my_db(DB_MAIN);
$universities = $db->fetchAll('SELECT distinct customer_university FROM wll_customer');
$counselors = $db->fetchAll('SELECT distinct customer_counselor FROM wll_customer');
$payments_ = $db->fetchAll('SELECT
    customer_counselor,
    customer_university,
    COUNT(DISTINCT customer_name) AS \'no of students\',
    SUM(DISTINCT wll_invoice.total_payable) AS payable,**//I want to make total_payable should GROUP BY customer_id** 
    SUM(wll_invoice.total_pay) AS paid,
    SUM(wll_invoice.due) AS balance
FROM
    wll_customer
        LEFT JOIN
    wll_invoice ON wll_invoice.customer_id = wll_customer.customer_id
GROUP BY customer_counselor,customer_university;');

$payments = [];
foreach ($payments_ as $payment)
$payments[$payment->customer_counselor][$payment->customer_university] = $payment;
?>

<table id="table_id" class='display table-bordered'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Sl</td>
        <td rowspan="2" >counselor</td>
<?php
    foreach ($universities as $key => $university){ ?>

        <td colspan="4" ><?=$university->customer_university ?> </td>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach ( $universities as $university){?>
        <td>no of students</td>
        <td>payable</td>
        <td>paid</td>
        <td>balance</td>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach ( $counselors as $counselor){?>
    <?php foreach ( $universities as $key => $university){
     $payment = $payments[$counselor->customer_counselor][$university->customer_university];
    ?>  <?php if(!$key){?>
         <td></td>
         <td><?=$counselor->customer_counselor?></td>
        <?php } ?>
        <td><?=(int)$payment->{'no of students'}?></td>
        <td><?=number_format($payment->payable,0,',','')?></td>
        <td><?=number_format($payment->paid,0,',','')?></td>
        <td><?=number_format($payment->balance,0,',','')?></td>
    <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: With which driver does it not work? And what's the error message?

Comment: That is ok if u can please help me with my query

Comment: That's not an answer to my questions??

Comment: Previously i was getting Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all() in /home/demosar30/public_html/admission/test3.php on line 165 error <br/> but i re write my code now its working fine

Comment: Btw. I wouldn't solve this in mysql, but use array_chunk combined with array_sum on the PHP side. This can be done in mysql but should be inefficient there.

Comment: Check the above code its working fine, Now don't have any version related issues, help me to solve my query

Comment: Yeah, as said, array_chunk + array_sum on PHP side. While you _can_ use a subquery, it shouldn't be the way to go…

Comment: Can you help me with the code

Comment: Not now, I'll this evening if nobody else has yet.

Comment: What exactly would be the issue of `$payable_per_customer = $db->fetchAll('SELECT customer_id, SUM(total_payable) AS payable FROM wll_invoice GROUP BY customer_id');` ? You cannot present two representations in one query. Either you present by the counselor/university _or_ you present by the customer?

Comment: In my query i have already done group by counsellor and university to display the date in multi dimensional array format as it is in the picture  present in the beginning of my question. Actually i have some values in total_payable column and i need to get the sum of distinct total_payable and that should be group by customer_id.

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure what you mean. Could you please extend your table image to also show that new column?

Comment: Ok i will update my table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120233/discussion-between-sha-and-bwoebi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is the code you are looking after:

```
<?php
define('DB_MAIN', 'localhost|user|password|database');

class my_db{

    private static $databases;
    private $connection;

    public function __construct($connDetails){
        if(!is_object(self::$databases[$connDetails])){
            list($host, $user, $pass, $dbname) = explode('|', $connDetails);
            $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";
            self::$databases[$connDetails] = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
        }
        $this->connection = self::$databases[$connDetails];
    }

    public function fetchAll($sql){
        $args = func_get_args();
        array_shift($args);
        $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute($args);
         return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
}

$db = new my_db(DB_MAIN);
$universities = $db->fetchAll('SELECT distinct customer_university FROM wll_customer order by customer_university');
/**
 * Adding Cummulative university 
 */
$cumulativeUniversity = new StdClass();
$cumulativeUniversity->customer_university = "CUMULATIVE TOTAL";
$universities[] = $cumulativeUniversity;

$counselors = $db->fetchAll('SELECT distinct customer_counselor FROM wll_customer order by customer_counselor');
$payments_ = $db->fetchAll('(SELECT 
    customer_counselor, 
    customer_university, 
    COUNT(distinct wll_invoice.customer_id) AS \'no of students\', 
    SUM(wll_invoice.total_payable) AS payable, 
    SUM(wll_invoice.total_pay) AS paid, 
    SUM(wll_invoice.due) AS balance 
    FROM wll_customer 
    LEFT JOIN wll_invoice 
     ON wll_invoice.customer_id = wll_customer.customer_id 
    GROUP BY customer_counselor, customer_university
    order by `customer_counselor`, `customer_name`)
UNION
    (SELECT 
    customer_counselor, 
    "CUMULATIVE TOTAL" as university, 
    COUNT(distinct wll_invoice.customer_id) AS \'no of students\', 
    SUM(wll_invoice.total_payable) AS payable, 
    SUM(wll_invoice.total_pay) AS paid, 
    SUM(wll_invoice.due) AS balance 
    FROM wll_customer 
    LEFT JOIN wll_invoice 
     ON wll_invoice.customer_id = wll_customer.customer_id 
    GROUP BY customer_counselor
    ORDER BY `customer_counselor`)');

$payments = [];
foreach ($payments_ as $payment)
$payments[$payment->customer_counselor][$payment->customer_university] = $payment;
?>

<table id="table_id" class='display table-bordered' border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" >Counselor</td>
    <?php
    foreach ($universities as $key => $university): ?>
        <td colspan="4" ><?=$university->customer_university ?> </td>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <?php foreach ( $universities as $university): ?>
        <td>no of students</td>
        <td>payable</td>
        <td>paid</td>
        <td>balance</td>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ( $counselors as $counselor):?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $counselor->customer_counselor;?>
            </td>
        <?php foreach ( $universities as $key => $university): 
            $payment = isset($payments[$counselor->customer_counselor][$university->customer_university]) ? $payments[$counselor->customer_counselor][$university->customer_university] : null;
            if($payment):?>
                <td><?=(int)$payment->{'no of students'}?></td>
                <td><?=number_format($payment->payable,0,',','')?></td>
                <td><?=number_format($payment->paid,0,',','')?></td>
                <td><?=number_format($payment->balance,0,',','')?></td>
            <?php else:?>
                <td colspan="4"></td>
            <?php endif?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I have used following query where I am using Union to append overall data by counsellor as well that you are looking for. Also if you have noticed in code, there I have appended a cumulative university object to the university list to process it same loop.

```
(SELECT 
customer_counselor, 
customer_university, 
COUNT(DISTINCT wll_invoice.customer_id) AS 'no of students', 
SUM(wll_invoice.total_payable) AS payable, 
SUM(wll_invoice.total_pay) AS paid, 
SUM(wll_invoice.due) AS balance 
FROM wll_customer 
LEFT JOIN wll_invoice 
 ON wll_invoice.customer_id = wll_customer.customer_id 
GROUP BY customer_counselor, customer_university
ORDER BY `customer_counselor`, `customer_name`)

UNION

(SELECT 
customer_counselor, 
"CUMULATIVE TOTAL" AS university, 
COUNT(DISTINCT wll_invoice.customer_id) AS 'no of students', 
SUM(wll_invoice.total_payable) AS payable, 
SUM(wll_invoice.total_pay) AS paid, 
SUM(wll_invoice.due) AS balance 
FROM wll_customer 
LEFT JOIN wll_invoice 
 ON wll_invoice.customer_id = wll_customer.customer_id 
GROUP BY customer_counselor
ORDER BY `customer_counselor`)
```

---

Try using this query for distinct value, but you really need to update your schema. This is just a temporary solution:

```
(SELECT 
customer_counselor, 
customer_university, 
COUNT(DISTINCT wll_invoice.customer_id) AS 'no of students', 
SUM(wll_invoice.total_payable) AS payable, 
SUM(final_pay) AS paid, 
SUM(wll_invoice.total_payable - final_pay) AS balance 
FROM wll_customer 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) max_id, customer_id, SUM(total_pay) final_pay FROM `wll_invoice`
GROUP BY customer_id, `total_payable`) AS wll_unique ON wll_unique.customer_id = wll_customer.`customer_id`

LEFT JOIN wll_invoice 
 ON wll_invoice.customer_id = wll_unique.customer_id AND `wll_invoice`.id = wll_unique.max_id
GROUP BY customer_counselor, customer_university
ORDER BY `customer_counselor`, `customer_name`)
UNION
(SELECT 
customer_counselor, 
"CUMULATIVE TOTAL" AS university, 
COUNT(DISTINCT wll_invoice.customer_id) AS 'no of students', 
SUM(wll_invoice.total_payable) AS payable, 
SUM(final_pay) AS paid, 
SUM(wll_invoice.total_payable - final_pay) AS balance 
FROM wll_customer 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) max_id, customer_id, SUM(total_pay) final_pay FROM `wll_invoice`
GROUP BY customer_id, `total_payable`) AS wll_unique ON wll_unique.customer_id = wll_customer.`customer_id`

LEFT JOIN wll_invoice 
 ON wll_invoice.customer_id = wll_unique.customer_id  AND `wll_invoice`.id = wll_unique.max_id
GROUP BY customer_counselor
ORDER BY `customer_counselor`)
```

Comment: Up vote for your answer, Actually i have some values in total_payable column in my database and i need to get the sum of distinct total_payable and that should be group by customer_id. Please add this to your code apart from that your code is working fine. So that i can award my bounty to you and i will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Sure, I will. Could you just send me sample of data from table that you have & update it in your question? If I am correct you have multiple enteries for same customer_id in wll_customer table as result you are getting duplicates?

Comment: I mean some sample schema of table so that I can update my queries accordingly.

Comment: The pic i have updated is the output  format, In wll_customer table  i have customer_id( Primary key),customer_university,customer_counsellor and in wll_invoice table i have  i have customer_id(Foreign key refers to wll_customer table) , payable,pay and due .

Comment: Ok, so you dont have some distinct key like primary in invoice table

Comment: Scenario is like this - i have made a form to update payments to wll_invoice table when each time customer pay some amount payable column will get duplicate entry. I mean only for the 1st time payable is correct suppose payable is 5000 paid is 1000 and due is 4000 will be inserted to wll_invoice table at 1st instalment, While paying 2nd instalment again Payable will be inserted as 5000 paid. so i'm thinking to fetch distinct data from database group by customer_name.

Comment: Ok, so you need to update your schema over here.. 

Suppose you have a customer with id 1 in University U1 as well as University U2, so in that case you will get total amount for same customer under both universities separately, the reason for this is you cannot categorise the payments by university over here. How do we know whether to show amount under U1 or U2?

So it my suggestion just add a university column in invoice table to categorise payments of customer by universities and respective conditions   .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120297/discussion-between-sha-and-anil-chauhan).

Comment: Ok so as per your scenario you need to have some "Invoice Number" in invoice table and use same "inovice number" for installments and then we can pick the last entry for that invoice. The reason for this is the user might have two different payments of 5000 for two different invoices so we need something to distinguish them.

Comment: Please visit chat room i replayed to your answer

Comment: I will get back on this by EOD.

Comment: Ok Thank you have a nice day

Comment: Edited please check!

Comment: Your awesome brother, your code is working like a charm :-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Your SQL should group by customer_university as well as customer_counselor:

```
SELECT 
customer_counselor, 
customer_university, 
COUNT(customer_name) AS \'no of students\', 
SUM(wll_invoice.total_payable) AS payable, 
SUM(wll_invoice.total_pay) AS paid, 
SUM(wll_invoice.due) AS balance 
FROM wll_customer 
LEFT JOIN wll_invoice 
 ON wll_invoice.customer_id = wll_customer.customer_id 
GROUP BY customer_counselor, customer_university
```

Comment: i'm getting same answer after GROUP BY customer_counselor, customer_counselor

Comment: No, you're probably getting a cached response or have changed the wrong script.

Comment: Yes now its working, I want to get consolidated total of all universities based on counsellor at the end how can i do that can you able to share the code

Comment: To make it clear i want to display next to that u2 1 more column called total it should display total number of students total paid and so on

Comment: That's a new question.

Comment: I wanted to achieve that in same query

Comment: upvote for your hint and i have updated my question please check it and suggest me any possible soultion